# OpenGL Framebuffer only writing to one face of cubemap

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, render-to-texture

I only seem to be able to render my scene into only one side of the cubemap. At the moment everything is hard-coded, I'm only trying to render the same view of the scene into each of the 6 faces of the cubemap, like so:

```
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_FboId);
    glViewport(0, 0, CUBEMAP_SIZE, CUBEMAP_SIZE);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    shader.bind();
    shader.loadProjectionMtx(glm::perspective(90.0f, 1.0f, 0.001f, 300.0f)[0][0]);
    shader.loadViewMtx(glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),  glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))[0][0]);

    for (unsigned int f = 0; f < 6; f++)
    {
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X + f, m_glId, 0);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++)
        {
            // Rendering the scene like normal
        }
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Depending on what "*GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_..._.*" value I give glFramebufferTexture2D() it always renders the scene into that one face - It's like it's not swapping the faces to render to according to what the value of "f" is in the loop.

But that one cube-face that does get rendered to, is always rendered into correctly.

Here's the cubemap & fbo creation code:

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_FboId);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_FboId);

    glGenTextures(1, &m_TxId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, m_TxId);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, CUBEMAP_SIZE, CUBEMAP_SIZE, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)nullptr);
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_DepthId);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_DepthId);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, CUBEMAP_SIZE, CUBEMAP_SIZE);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TxId, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_DepthId);

    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

    int fbo_Status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (fbo_Status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) printf(" ::ENGINE:: FBO Creation Failed! glError: %i\n", fbo_Status);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I have found 2 other related cases online but neither was resolved

Comment: I think you should replace `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X` 
 with `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X` because it's the first cube map face in order.

Comment: `glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TxId, 0);` This line should give an error, since `m_TxId` is not a 2D texture. It's a cube map texture.

Comment: Hey Nicol, thanks I've removed the glFramebufferTexture2D() line from the fbo initialisation code, it was unnecessarily there anyway, still there's only one face being rendered into :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one depth buffer. Since you render the exact same into each face, and assuming the default `glDepthFunc()` comparison mode of `GL_LESS`, all fragments generated after the first iteration will fail the depth test.

You need to clear the depth buffer in the loop. Clearing the color buffer might or might not be necessary, depending on how you draw your scene.

Comment: You are a star :) I've been stuck on this for over 2 days, thank you so much for helping me out :)